# Morse Code Translator - Calling a function within an if statement using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

`I'm trying to write code that starts with a question asking the user if they want to encode or decode to/from morse. Based on their response (1 or 2), it runs through an if statement, and will call the required function(s).

It will take a user's input via user_input() and either return it in morse code, or return it in English, based on their choice to encode or decode. The encoding aspect works, but I cannot get the decode_morse() function to work within the entire program.

I'm getting an error on the calling of function encode_or_decode() at the bottom, and also 'TypeError: decode_morse() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data''

```
# Dictionary representing English to morse code chart
ENG_TO_MORSE_DICT = {'a':'.-', 'b':'-...', 'c':'-.-.',
        'd':'-..', 'e':'.', 'f':'..-.', 'g':'--.', 'h':'....', 
        'i':'..', 'j':'.---', 'k':'-.-', 'l':'.-..', 'm':'--', 
        'n':'-.', 'o':'---', 'p':'.--.', 'q':'--.-', 'r':'.-.', 
        's':'...', 't':'-', 'u':'..-', 'v':'...-', 'w':'.--', 
        'x':'-..-', 'y':'-.--', 'z':'--..', ' ':'/', 'A':'.-', 
        'B':'-...', 'C':'-.-.', 'D':'-..', 'E':'.', 'F':'..-.', 
        'G':'--.','H':'....', 'I':'..', 'J':'.---', 'K':'-.-', 
        'L':'.-..', 'M':'--', 'N':'-.', 'O':'---', 'P':'.--.', 
        'Q':'--.-', 'R':'.-.', 'S':'...', 'T':'-', 'U':'..-',
        'V':'...-', 'W':'.--', 'X':'-..-', 'Y':'-.--', 'Z':'--..'
}
# Dictionary representing morse code to English 
MORSE_TO_ENG_DICT = {
        ".-": "A", "-...": "B", "-.-.": "C", "-..": "D",
        ".": "E", "..-.": "F", "--.": "G", "....": "H",
        "..": "I", ".---": "J", "-.-": "K", ".-..": "L", 
        "--": "M", "-.": "N", "---": "O", ".--.": "P",
        " --.-": "Q", ".-.": "R", "...": "S", "-": "T",
        "..-": "U", "...-": "V", ".--": "W", "-..-": "X",
        "-.--": "Y", "--..": "Z", "/":' '
    }
def encode_or_decode():  
    choice = int(input("Please select 1 to encode to morse, or 2 to decode from morse "))  
    if choice == 1:
     message_to_encode()
    elif choice == 2:
     decode_morse()
    else:
     print("Please select option 1 or option 2")

# Defining a global variable for user's input to be used within multiple functions
def user_input(): 
    global data 
    data = str(input("What message do you want to translate using the Morse cipher? "))
def morse_encrypt(data):  
        for letter in data:  
            print(ENG_TO_MORSE_DICT[letter], end = ' ')

# Defining a function for user-inputted data, using isalpha method to mandate only alphabet letters & spaces as input
def message_to_encode(): 
    user_input()
    if data.replace(' ', '').isalpha():
     morse_encrypt(data)  
    else: 
     print("Only text allowed in message")

def decode_morse():
    results = []
    for item in data.split(' '):
        results.append(MORSE_TO_ENG_DICT.get(item))
    results = ''.join(results)
    return results.lower()
    
def decode_morse(data):
    results = []
    for item in data.split(' '):
        results.append(MORSE_TO_ENG_DICT.get(item))
    results = ''.join(results)
    return results.lower()
encode_or_decode()
```

I've tried running a similar decode function in isolation with its own user input and this works fine... but I don't want to duplicate the user input function in the main program, so have tried to use the data variable from the user_input(_) function, which throws up errors.

```
MORSE_TO_ENG_DICT = {
        ".-": "A", "-...": "B", "-.-.": "C", "-..": "D",
        ".": "E", "..-.": "F", "--.": "G", "....": "H",
        "..": "I", ".---": "J", "-.-": "K", ".-..": "L", 
        "--": "M", "-.": "N", "---": "O", ".--.": "P",
        " --.-": "Q", ".-.": "R", "...": "S", "-": "T",
        "..-": "U", "...-": "V", ".--": "W", "-..-": "X",
        "-.--": "Y", "--..": "Z", "/":' '
    }

def decode_morse(morse_data):
    results = []
    for item in morse_data.split(' '):
        results.append(MORSE_TO_ENG_DICT.get(item))
    results = ''.join(results)
    return results.lower()


morse_data = str(input("What morse message do you want to decode using the Morse cipher? "))
print(decode_morse(morse_data))
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `decode_morse()` is defined twice: one with a parameter, and one without. Try to change the names of the functions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out - I needed to print the results of the decode_morse() function and remove 'return results.lower()' as this stopped the print from executing. The correct code was:

```
def decode_morse(data):
    results = []
    for item in data.split(' '):
        results.append(MORSE_TO_ENG_DICT.get(item))
    results = ''.join(results)
    print(results.lower())
encode_or_decode()
```